# Python does not let me print turkish characters

Tags: python, encoding, printing, character-encoding

Even though i add a comment to change the encoding to utf-8 i get an error. I can not print ü ğ ş ç İ Ş Ç Ğ Ö Ü

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("ğ")
```

The error i get

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

I am using virtual studio 2022 and Python 3.10 (i think the latest ?)

Comment: You need to use an environment that supports an output encoding of UTF-8. So, it will work if you have a UTF-8 terminal. It won't work on a normal Windows command prompt.

Comment: @ankitbatra22 thank you so much for the tip. I actually went to the language settings and UTF-8 settings was not active. That solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not related to python or any code.

My command prompt window was not adjusted to utf-8. I changed it in the language settings. Thanks for your reply nonetheless sidereal !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `encoding='utf-8'`

Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510650/how-can-i-replace-unicode-characters-with-turkish-characters-in-a-text-file-with) question already?
There are different unicodes for the Turkish language, you can 'decrypt' them by using the list of unicodes. Take a look at the link I provided